# How to publish LIKE feature for Photo/Video using object_id we get from Photo/Album/Video table

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How to publish LIKE feature for Photo/Video using object_id we get from Photo/Album/Video table.
Comments.add has object_id, through which we can publish comments on any photo/album/Video.
but how to LIKE the same.

Thanks in Advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can use GraphApi to 'like' posts. Only user can like photos, videos, etc.

Comment: For Desktop application, how can user LIKE photo/Video, but user can comment on photo/Video. Because comments.add has object_id. Using Graph API,how can you like the Photo/Video?